# Component not getting model data that Template gets?

Tags: ember.js

I am an extreme newbie, for which I apologize, but I'm not finding this...

In templates/editor/journal.hbs, this works:

```
<h2>Journal template</h2>
<select>
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Periodicals:</option>
  {{#each model as |journal|}}
    <option value="{{journal.id}}"> {{journal.name}}</option> {{journal}}
  {{/each}}
</select>
{{outlet}}
```

But the same code, in my component (journal-list), does not...
with journal.hbs changed to

```
<h2>Journal template</h2>
{{journal-list title="Crazy Test" model=journal}}
{{outlet}}
```

And that code in journal-list.hbs,

```
{{yield}}
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<select>
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Periodicals:
</option>
  {{#each model as |journal|}}
    <option value="{{journal.id}}"> {{journal.name}}</option> 
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

all stubs generated by ember generate, I do get the title but the listview is unpopulated.

What magic am I missing?  Do I need to configure a route to the component, for example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Uggah.  I did spend over an hour on that before posting!

It's simple.  Instead of journal.hbs having `model=journal`, it needed `model=model`.